# $d$ is composite and $d|m$, $\exists b,c$ such that $m = bc$ and $d$ divides neither $b$ nor $c$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove the following statement or construct a counterexample: If $d$ is
>   composite and $d$ divides $m$, then there exist integers $b,c$ such
>   that $m = bc$ and $d$ divides neither $b$ nor $c$.

$d=p_1^{r_1} ...p_k^{r_k}$ then $\sum r_i \ge 2$.
$m=da$, some integer $a$. In case $d$ doesn't divide $a$. Can we simply separate the prime factors to get $b$ and $c$?

Comment: Hint:  since $d$ is composite let $d=m$.

Comment: I get the impression that both $d$ and $m$ are given, so we don't get to make that choice.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Ah, probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ has at least 2 distinct prime factors then the claim is true, but what if $d=p^2, m=p^3$, for some prime $p$?

However, if $pq|d$ for distinct primes $p,q$, then we can simply write $m=p^km'$, where $p\not|\, m'$, and then let $b=p^k, c=m'$.